# Iterate and print argument passed through Tornado

Tags: javascript, html, tornado

I am using a tornado framework which renders a html page(trial.html). Variable "pn" has a list [u'S1', u'S2'].How HTML can iterate and print the arguments passed through tornado as a list?

```
class Setup(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        pn= cdict[room]['panel']    
        self.render("trial.html",pn=json.dumps(pn))
```

The following is a part of my html code:

```
<li> <a href="setup?nw={{nw}}">{{(pn) }}</li></a>
```

I want the list to be rendered as :

S1

S2

where both S1 and S2 have individual href.But now it gets rendered as
    [S1', S2'] with a single href.
SO how do I split the list in HTML and assign individual href to the elements in a link.

Comment: Are you sure that's JS you're using?

Comment: No it is html , I read through the Internet and found that javascript has an option to iterate , but I couldn't find a way to pass the arguments and to split the individual elements of a list.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jabIJwqvufDaZkX3685D?p=preview .In the following link the list is hard-coded.But I want to pass it as an argument in my tornado.

Comment: Don't use `json.dumps`. Just pass `pn=pn`.

Comment: @xyres if I don't use json.dumps it renders as Unicode strings.I get the following on screen     [u'S1', u'S2']

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. Don't use `json.dumps`, unless you need it (in your case you don't).
2. Use `for` loop in your template to iterate over the list.
3. Use [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html).

Here's how you can iterate over a list in a template:

```
{% for item in your_list %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% end %}
```

The above code will create an `li` element for every item in `your_list`.

Comment: Thanks a lot xyres.I edited the code                                                      {% for item in pn %}
   <li><a href="setup?nw={{nw}}"> {{ item }}</li>
       {% end %}